# C# exception handling (with a string given to a constructor)

Tags: c#, exception

I have a WeekdayException class that has the ToString().
I want to return the string set up in Constructor ("Illegal weekday: " + wday) with ToString(). How to access the string?

```
using System;

class WeekdayException : ApplicationException {
    public WeekdayException(String wday) : base("Illegal weekday: " + wday) {}

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "HELLO" + ???;
    }
}

class TryCatchFinally 
{
    public static void Main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            throw new WeekdayException("thrown by try");
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Catch ..." + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

And is this (making and using ToString()) the method that C# programmers use? If not, what's the way to go?

Comment: Why override ToString? Isn't the parent's version going to do what you want? Otherwise, call some of your own (inherited) methods to get the data, or use an instance variable

Comment: Inheriting from `ApplicationException` has been dis-recommended for quite some time.  Inherit directly from `Exception`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can access `wday` specifically by adding a `private` member variable (but see below):

```
class WeekdayException : ApplicationException {
    private readonly string weekday;
    public WeekdayException(String wday) : base("Illegal weekday: " + wday) {
        this.weekday = wday;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "HELLO " + this.weekday;
    }
}
```

> And is this (making and using `ToString()`) the method that C# programmers use? If not, what's the way to go?

Typically for exceptions you set and use the `Message` property which is set when you invoke the constructor for the base `ApplicationException`.

```
class WeekdayException : ApplicationException {
    public WeekdayException(string weekday)
        : base("Illegal weekday: " + weekday) { }
}
```

Then:

```
try {
    throw new WeekdayException("Tuesday");
}
catch(WeekdayException weekdayException) {
    Console.WriteLine(weekdayException.Message);
}
```

Finally, don't abbreviate names like `weekday` to shorter variants like `wday`. Just use the full name.

Answer (score 1):

The [`ApplicationException(string)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd34f147.aspx) sets the `ApplicationException`'s `Message` property, so you should be able to use `Message` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you `override` the `Message` property:

```
class WeekdayException : ApplicationException
{
    private readonly string _message;

    public override string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }
    }

    public WeekdayException(String wday)
    {
        _message = "Illegal weekday: " + wday;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Message;
    }
}
```